To what extent are pure mathematics used in data science and Machine Learning?
To what extent are pure mathematics used in data scientist and Machine Learning? I came from a pure mathematics backpack that recently pivot to the data science field. However I'm pretty disappointed as all I'm doing is just mundane stuff like data cleaning and quering data from databases using sql. I've used none of my pure math knowledge so far in data science which I was promised data science will be full of math. By pure math I meant topics like differential geometry, functional analysis, topology etc. Should I change my job to get another role that involves such interesting math topics? Or was there even such roles in data science to being with where I'm able to apply all the cool math topics. Anyone would advice please?
